# Stored Procedure call with parameters in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a working controller for another stored procedure in the database, but I am trying to test another.

When I request the URL;

> http://host.com/Map?minLat=0&maxLat=50&minLng=0&maxLng=50

I get the following error message, which is understandable but I can't seem to find out why it occurs;

> Procedure or function
>   'esp_GetPlacesWithinGeoSpan' expects
>   parameter '@MinLat', which was not
>   supplied.

This is the code I am using.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace prototype.Controllers
{
    public class MapController : Controller
    {
        //Initial variable definitions
        //Array with chars to be used with the Trim() methods
        char[] lastComma = { ',' };

        //Minimum and maximum lat/longs for queries
        float _minLat;
        float _maxLat;
        float _minLng;
        float _maxLng;


        //Creates stringbuilder object to store SQL results
        StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();

        //Defines which SQL-server to connect to, which database, and which user
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(...connection string here...);

        // 
        // HTTP-GET: /Map/ 

        public string CallProcedure_getPlaces(float minLat, float maxLat, float minLng, float maxLng)
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("esp_GetPlacesWithinGeoSpan", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MinLat", _minLat);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaxLat", _maxLat);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MinLng", _minLng);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaxLng", _maxLng);


                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        json.AppendFormat("\"{0}\":{{\"c\":{1},\"f\":{2}}},", reader["PlaceID"], reader["PlaceName"], reader["SquareID"]);
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            return "{" + json.ToString().TrimEnd(lastComma) + "}";
        }


        //http://host.com/Map?minLat=0&maxLat=50&minLng=0&maxLng=50
        public ActionResult Index(float minLat, float maxLat, float minLng, float maxLng)
        {
            _minLat = minLat;
            _maxLat = maxLat;
            _minLng = minLng;
            _maxLng = maxLng;

            return Content(CallProcedure_getPlaces(_minLat, _maxLat, _minLng, _maxLng));
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, you really shouldn't be performing data access in your controllers. This is best achieved by using another layer, such as a repository.

Comment: Could you expand on that? Or perhaps show me an example? I'm not very familiar with asp.net at all, I just figured this was a simple and therefore decent way of doing it. I'd love to learn.

Comment: @cc0 Here's a great and perfectly simple example of using ADO.net (SqlConnection) with a Repository in MVC: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6694195/555798

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `CommandType` is wrong. It should be:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Since you're using `CommandType.Text`, my guess would be that ADO.NET is trying to map parameters into the text of the query rather than generating the proper call to the Stored Procedure.

Comment: Awesome! Lol. I can't believe I missed that! I was using the text to test before I had created the procedure. Thanks! Mental hiccup there.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to pass the parameters using the text type

```
CommandType.Text
```

then you should pass the parameters like this:

```
GetPlacesWithinGeoSpan @MinLat, @MaxLat, @MinLng, @MaxLng
```

Because the way your doing it its like your passing parameters but it don't map to anything so it's ignored.

Hope it helps