# is it the right way to do the project with asp.net mvc 4 and stored procedures?

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures

Can you please spend ur time 4 this and help me as it is a big project if we do mistakes noe we will repeat the same mistake in next 3 years.

we are starting a new big project in asp.net mvc4, Html5 and CSS3 (We preffer these Because our application should target tablet, desktop, mobile).
 So I feel bec its new we can better start with code first approach(latest) like first creating classes and prepare db(sql express) and deploy well and also we have support of EF migrations, So I think that way the proj become more successful and maintainable easily.
But the small concern with the manager, I dont know whether he is correct or iam wrong bec he has good experience in working but he is also new to MVC. below is my query ive explained pls look into this,

-Database with tables are ready.
-Now we have to start the project. (I think we can do code first reverse engineering and start)
But, For that our manager asked our team to prefer and write stored procedures, and use asp.net mvc 4?
My question is, is it the right way to do the project with that combination? Why am asking you is I have been watching videos/tutorials through online they never said the samples with that combination and all are saying with out using stored procedures, is it any problem like performance we will not get as we are using storedprocedures through EF OR because we are using stored procedures in backend we will get performance and maintaing easily as our PM says,

Iam totally confused???? please help me in this if you have solution.

Comment: -1 for a totally confused blob of text with chat-slang and no formatting .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no any issue using stored procedure in MVC, you can go for it. There would be worth reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698151/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-sql-vs-ado-net-with-stored-procedures) about your performance question.

If controller is not depended on the implementation of data access layer then no matter what you use whether EF or Stored procedure, you are good to go.

[Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) already explain it about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694098/using-asp-net-mvc-with-classic-ado-net).

Answer (score 0):

That videos doesn't represend examples of using stored procedures, because they doesn't need stored procedures! All of results from SPs can be achived by EF easily and with much less effort and waisting times.

However, you should consider 3 things:

1) It seems that you all are new to EF. So, using EF is a potentially thechnical risk for your project!

2) Keep in mind that EF will cause some overhead to your app and if you're creating an app which works with huge data or should handle many requests at once, maybe it's better for you to keep going through SPs.

3) From the other hand, if you get familar with EF, it will dramatically progress your project fast and easy because of its useful abstractions and conventions.

So, first know your project, then deside which way you should go...