# asp.net mvc c# with sql without ORM

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

So I have to make a asp.net project with `SQL Server` database, the problem is that I have to do it without any ORM-with a specific DB controller and I have always used the Entity Framework which IS an `ORM`.

I have no idea from where to begin. How do I collect the data and send it the controller with the `html.helpers` and how to structure the db controller?

I am not allowed to use `Linq` either just SQL. As much as I can see from the others questions I should use the `SQL command` class but its not explained structurally.

What I am asking here is just for the basics.How do I get it from the html helper to the database without ORM and what will I need for that as clases and models,how to relate them and if possible for a simple example.

Comment: Look through Artist, Exhibition, or Objects controllers here and you can see how it is done:  https://github.com/smoore4moma/tms-api/tree/master/tms-api/Controllers

Comment: explore oledbconnection namespace, be excited on your task, ORM sometimes made us lazy forgetting about some important tasks since it is already wrapped

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you mentioned, you can use "classic" SQL commands with ADO.NET. Here is a good example:
[Using ASP.Net MVC with Classic ADO.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694098/using-asp-net-mvc-with-classic-ado-net)

Another way, and in my opinion a very fast and convenient way, is to use the [Dapper framework](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net).
I would recommend you to use Dapper with Stored Procedures. It's a good trade-off between ORM (like Entity Framework) and classical SQL commands. I can show you an example if you give me a business case.

Comment: + 1 yah dapper is also good when it comes to performance, the only downside is to write that very long codes :)

Comment: Dapper is a great choice especially if you have to leverage something that doesn't have an EF provider.